# Cropping network image from up and bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I cut any image during display from upper and bottom with fix amount.

```
Container(
                height: 200,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                    image: NetworkImage(articles[index].imageUrl!),
                  ),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: try to use BoxFit.fitWidth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [flutter document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html):

**BoxFit.cover:**

As small as possible while still covering the entire target box.

[image]

so try using **BoxFit.fitWidth:**

Make sure the full width of the source is shown, regardless of whether this means the source overflows the target box vertically.

[image]

Then you can provide your custom `aspect ratio` to crop it based on your desirable size, by the help of `AspectRatio` widget:

```
AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 400 / 300,
          child:Container(
                height: 200,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                    image: NetworkImage(articles[index].imageUrl!),
                  ),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                ),
              ),)
```